# Extracting line number of a txt file in Python

Tags: python, file, line-numbers

I want to know if there is a way to find the line number of a line in a text file, using Python.

So, for example, if we have the file `textfile.txt`:

```
abc
deff
ghi
jkl
EOF
```

Then I'd like a function like `func(FILE,TEXT)`, that would work in the following way:

```
Input:  func(textfile.txt, "ghi")
Output: 3
```

Comment: Why do you want the line number? What are you ultimately trying to do?

Comment: I have an output file with information. I want to find the line in which is written "Something and something else" and to copy that line and the following "n" lines to another file.

Comment: `with open('my_file.txt') as f: for line_num, line in enumerate(f): ` that's a start

Comment: It's not a definition, is the output I want to get after executing the function...

Comment: You can't use python keywords as variable names. `def` is reserved for function definitions.

Comment: It was just tje second line of the text file. I changed it to the third line so the examole is clearer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in one line with `next()` called on a generator that uses the `enumerate()` function to get the index of the line.

So, as a function:

```
def func(f, t):
    return next(i for i, l in enumerate(open(f).read().split('\n'), 1) if l == t)
```

which would be called through something like:

```
func('textfile.txt', 'ghi') # --> 3
```

---

*note: the `enumerate(..., 1)` trick was from `@KeyurPotdar`, so creds*

Comment: Instead of `+1` at the end, you could also do `enumerate(..., 1)`.

Comment: @KeyurPotdar Nice one :)

Answer (score 0):

```
file_name="test.txt"
phrase="line3"
with open(file_name) as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f, 1):
        if phrase in line:
           print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that's waht you're looking for:

```
def fn(fname, substr):
    with open(fname) as text:
        for n, line in enumerate(text, start=1):
            if line.startswith(substr):
                return n
    return -1
```

Don't be afraid to study the python docs on string functions, file I/O, context managers etc. You'll be shocked on how easy things like this are to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

This might help.

```
def LineNumber(phrase,textObjext):
    for i, line in enumerate(textObjext, 1):
        if phrase in line:
           return i

file_name="test.txt"
phrase="deff"
text = open(file_name,'r')
line = LineNumber(phrase,text)
print(line)
```